# Is mongodb's cursor.count() the actual count?

Tags: python, mongodb, count, pymongo

When I was scanning through a collection in **mongodb** and editting all of the items, I got this question: *scanning counter i can be larger than cursor.count().* Why is this happenning? Can anyone figured it out?

db.baiduwords.find().count() = 805280

db.baiduwords.find().size() = 805280

but i goes to 1498400 or more.

```
import pymongo
if __name__=='__main__':
    client = pymongo.MongoClient()
    i = 0
    collection = client.baike.baiduwords.find()
    for item in collection:
        i += 1
        MajorClass = []
        for cl in item['C']:
            c = cl
            while(1):
                a = client.baike.baiduclass.find({'s':c})
                if a.count():
                    a = a[0]
                    if a['f'] == u'Root':
                        MajorClass.append(c)
                        break
                    else:
                        c = a['f']
                else:
                    break
        item['MC'] = list(set(MajorClass))
        client.baike.baiduwords.save(item)
        if i%100 == 0:
            print "%d/%d"%(i, collection.count())
```

PS: printShardingStatus: this db does not have sharding enabled.

Comment: Is this a sharded collection?

Comment: I don't know. But I've never configured it to be sharded.

Comment: What if you'll use `size()` instead of `count()` here?

Comment: db.baiduwords.find().size() is 805280 , same as .count()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that when you save your item, the updated document may move causing the cursor to return the document more than once.

From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-isolate-cursors-from-intervening-write-operations:

> As a cursor returns documents, other operations may interleave with the query: if some of these operations are updates that cause the document to move (in the case of a table scan, caused by document growth,) or that change the indexed field on the index used by the query; then the cursor will return the same document more than once.

Comment: Thank you! I use collection = client.baike.baiduwords.find(snapshot=True) and it goes normally.